# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_",referenced from:

Tags: ios7, ios-simulator, clang, sip, voip

Hello i am getting the following errors and warnings if i build the program on simulator,but if i run it on the real  device these things disappears?why do i get this?any idea?

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/interaxisnetworks/Desktop/Test/TestProg/audiocall/PortSIPLib.framework/PortSIPLib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/interaxisnetworks/Desktop/Test/TestProg/audiocall/PortSIPLib.framework/PortSIPLib (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PortSIPSDK", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Once i run the app on phone,i  am not getting these warnings at all.But sometimes when i open the program and do build on simulator i get these errors and warnings.

i have gone through answers for similar problems,added app delegate.m in build settings,still these errors are coming.

Answer (score 1):

The PortSIPLib.framework you tried to link your app with seems to be iOS only. You should ask the provider of the framework for a binary that is suitable for the simulator. If he can't or won't provide one, then there is nothing much you can do, I'm afraid.